# Policies in functions/methods

Tags: c#

Out of curiosity (I just want to know how is it done in C#) how are you supplying a policy to a function/method? For example, if I have a function which sorts in C++ I can do something like this:

```
std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(), Comparator<char>());
```

where v is a vector, v.begin is beginning of it and v.end end of this vector and this curious Comparator() is a policy which specifies on what critceria is this vector to be sorted. It can be for example that sorting will be done ignoring case of a char etc etc.
How would you do the same in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sorting, you'd usually pass in a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) or an [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx). That can be used to compare any two elements. (`IComparer<T>` is effectively the interface form of the `Comparison<T>` delegate.)

So for sorting examples:

```
// Using IComparer<T>
listOfStrings.Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

// Handy default comparer...
listOfInts.Sort(Comparer<int>.Default);

// Using Comparison<T> in a slightly odd way (sorting dates by day of month)
listOfDates.Sort((x, y) => x.Day.CompareTo(y.Day));
```

In general, as of .NET 3.5 and C# 3 (which makes it a breeze to create delegates) using a delegate can make things really easy when you only need a single operation to determine the "policy". For things like equality, however, you may need to use more than one operation, so an interface becomes useful - `IEqualityComparer<T>` has both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, for example.

Comment: @Jon so could you please provide an example. I just want to see the syntax and how it looks aesthetically.

Comment: @Jon first example, so I understand that user can implement the "policy" OrdinalIgnoreCase on it's own (or some other policy) and use it on a string object? For example if I would like to sort them in order reversed lexicographical I would for example define LexicographicalReversed and use it instead of OridinalIgnoreCase? And what about sorting just part of a container? Just first 2000 records for example from a database of 5, 000, 000?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: You'd use it to compare a pair of strings. Note that `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is just a static property on the StringComparer class, which returns a StringComparer, which implements `IComparer<string>`. You could implement your  `IComparer<string>` yourself though - it's just an interface.

Comment: As for sorting just part of a container - I can't remember seeing anything to do that in .NET, to be honest... nor can I ever remember wanting it. In LINQ you could do OrderBy(...).Take(2000) though.

Comment: @Jon sorry for delay in response. Jon so could we go line by line (just the interfaces, don't mind the implementation details) and try to do the same thing you in C# and I in C++? I just want to see what the code looks like, what the scalability of the is. And if for example I implement my LexReverse will I be able to also use it on type different to string without reimplementing nor writing similar algorithm from scratch? Could you please provide (extended if possible) examples of doing so? As for sorting only part of container, well, on the contrary - I do it quite often.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: If you want to implement a generic sort of comparison, you'd need to make it a generic type. Generics in C# work very differently to templates in C++. I don't have time to go through every little aspect of sorting, but if you want to see a generic implementation, read parts 26a-26d of my Edulinq blog posts:  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx - these are slightly different as they're ordering elements by keys, but there are still custom key comparisons.

Comment: @Jon I've read those parts of your blog that you've mentioned in your last comment. God, for something what in C++ takes literaly one line of actual code you have fully blown class with number of helper methods. God thanks for C++. To me C# is basicaly a Java from Microsoft. Long, contorted and slow.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: so you think there's no library code behind that one C++ line of code? Don't forget that my blog posts are *implementing* LINQ to Objects... and your C++ line of code is performing comparisons on the whole object rather than a key projection. Feel free to ignore C#, but personally I find it's actually rather more compact than C++ for a number of things. Take a reasonably complex LINQ query expression, and convert that into C++... I think you'll find it's considerably more code.

Comment: @Jon but LINQ isn't a language per say is it? C# is a language and I'm comparing C# to C++ and not even on lines of code, but on aesthetics and (surprise, surprise) readability. Do not want to mention performance. I'm sorry it's not like I'm being awkward but the just cannot compete. And you're saying thake linq and compare it's expression with C++? You talking about comparing interface to a language. If I was going to reimplement functionality of linq in C++ I would prove you that interface would be more natural and more intuitive.

Comment: continue And what's more important the interface of it wouldn't be in any way different to "not database query" part of code. That's one of many things what C# is missing. But anyway, I'm not here to try to prove anything, my question was purely out of curiosity. Thanks for your answer and your time.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Part of LINQ is in the language - the translation of query expressions to non-query expression form, along with lambda expressions which are required for the whole thing to work. Your comment about "not database query" makes it sound like you fundamentally don't understand LINQ. Database queries and non-database queries can be expressed in one consistent form... that's half the point. Personally I'll take the readability of C# over that of C++ any day of the week.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: If you feel you can implement LINQ in C++, go ahead. The fact that the "LIN" part is "Language Integrated" suggests that you'll have an uphill struggle... but maybe in trying to do it, you'll gain an appreciation of what LINQ is actually all about.

Comment: @Jon but you cannot compare LINQ to C++. If anything you should compare LINQ to SQL but not to C++. Just to make it clear that I do understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: But query expressions are part of the C# language, in anticipation of appropriate implementations. They make it easier to work with collections, whether in a database or in-process. Why should they be excluded from any comparison? It's probably best to compare the simplest way of accomplishing tasks, given a "normal" working environment (e.g. using boost if you want).

Comment: @Jon yes, fair point. I would really like to see real comparision (just like you've said), how easy is to achieve a task, how effective the performance is, within how many lines this task could be implemented, how readable this code would be and how easily maintainable and portable will it be.